# How to check null value in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Can anyone tell me how to write this check in Sql Server 2008 for Null parameter. I need to know how can I write the condition statement inside the sql query instead of outside the query part.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @SelItm NVARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @Input1 VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @Input2 VARCHAR(100) 

SET selitm = 'Select * from table as tbla where tbla.Id='''+@Input1+ ''' (Case when   @Input2 is not null then and tbla.supid='''+@Input2+ 
''' else '''' end)' 

EXEC Sp_executesql 
@SelItm
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss something between your @input1 and where the case should begin.

```
Select * 
from table as tbla 
where tbla.Id='''+@Input1+ ''' **SOMETHING_MISSING_HERE**  
 (Case when   @Input2 is not null then tbla.supid='''+@Input2+ ''' else '''' end)
```

When you use a case, you'll need the "returning" (so to speak) element of the CASE which is what's in the THEN part of the case - to compare to something.

So for example:

```
'Select * 
from table as tbla 
where tbla.Id='''+@Input1+ ''' 
AND tbla.supid= 
   (Case when ''' + @Input2 + ''' is not null then '''+@Input2+ ''' else '''' end)'
```

This will check that `tbla.Id = @Input1` AND if @Input2 is not null that `supid = @Input2` or if @Input2 is null that `supid = ''`

Notice the placement of `supid =` compared to your example.

It is something along that line you need?
And if it is - then you can simplify the statement by using ISNULL:

```
'Select * from table as tbla 
 where tbla.Id='''+@Input1+ ''' AND tbla.supid= ISNULL(''' + @Input2 + ''' , '')'
```

**However**, just to make matters a bit more complex; then you will run into a NULL issue where you try to add NULL to a string for your dynamic SQL, and adding NULL will result in NULL.
So in your example, the best place to check for NULL will be to check the @Input2 variable before the query:
So when you have:

```
DECLARE @Input2 VARCHAR(100)
```

then after the variable has been set, you should check for NULL before using it in a dynamic SQL statement:

```
SET @Input2 = ISNULL(@Input2, '')
```

And **then** use the variable in a dynamic sql statement.

Comment: I want it to be something like if parameter is not null then include in where clause otherwise no need to include. Pls see my edited query.

Comment: Then do something like `AND tbla.supId = ISNULL(@Input2, tlba.supId)`
then you do not need dynamic sql string to execute. If it is null supId will just match supId which is always true otherwise, it'll compare to @Input2

Comment: It is not working for me `'Select * from table as tbla 
 where tbla.Id='''+@Input1+ ''' AND tbla.supid= ISNULL(''' + @Input2 + ''' , tbla.supid)'`.

Comment: Did you see what I wrote in my post about NULL values? It's very likely that which is the issue. But you do not need to place it in a string and execute. Just run it "normally" and not via the execute.: `Select * from table as tbla where tbla.Id= @Input1 AND tbla.supid= ISNULL(@Input2, tbla.supid)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this for each possibly-null parameter,Lets chect Input1 first,I hope this code will help you.

```
 AND (Input1= @Input1 OR (Input1 IS NULL AND @Input1 IS NULL))
```